# Java UDP Server Programming

Tags: java, udp

I am just looking for a little guidance on a project I am working on... I have the general idea but can't seem to get code placed correctly.

The goal is as follows:
Write a UDP 'CompressionServer' that will take input from the user until it sees a "magic string" at which time it will create a compressed and uncompressed version of the file in the file system.

So, I need to integrate the following "Zip" code in to my UDP server code (which already creates the uncompressed file)... That is where I am stuck at now. My first few attempts had the Zip code after I write to "fout" but that failed to create a ZIP file.

I guess the main point here is what are the key pieces of the ZIP code that I should include and what would be the best spot to place them in my server code... Any help is appreciated!

**Zip Code:**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.zip.*;

public class Zip {
   static final int BUFFER = 2048;
   public static void main (String argv[]) {
      try {
         String fileInput = argv[0];
         String fileOutput = argv[1];

         BufferedInputStream origin = null;

         // Create a file output stream
         FileOutputStream dest = new 
           FileOutputStream(fileOutput);

         ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new 
           BufferedOutputStream(dest));

         //out.setMethod(ZipOutputStream.DEFLATED);
         byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER];

         // get a list of files from current directory
          FileInputStream fi = new 
            FileInputStream(fileInput);

          origin = new 
            BufferedInputStream(fi, BUFFER);

          ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(fileInput);
          out.putNextEntry(entry);
          int count;
          while((count = origin.read(data, 0, 
            BUFFER)) != -1) {
             out.write(data, 0, count);
          }
         origin.close();
         out.close();
      } catch(Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

**Server Code:**

```
import java.net.*;  // for DatagramSocket, DatagramPacket, and InetAddress
import java.io.*;   // for IOException

public class CompressionServer {

  private static final int ECHOMAX = 65535;  // Maximum size of echo datagram
  private static final int BUFFER = 2048;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    int servPort = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

    DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(servPort);
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(new byte[ECHOMAX], ECHOMAX);

    for (;;)/>/>/>  {  // Run forever, receiving and echoing datagrams
          socket.receive(packet);     // Receive packet from client
      // Get data from packet
      byte[] data = packet.getData();
      // Create new string from bytes w/ offset -- contains name of file
      String fileName = new String(data, 0, packet.getLength());
      // Create file output stream w/ file name
      FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(fileName.trim());

      // Receive bytes from socket, write bytes to file & flush
      while (true) {
        // Receive
        socket.receive(packet);
        data = packet.getData();
        String tmp = new String(data, 0, packet.getLength());

        // Determine if need to break from loop
        if (tmp.indexOf("--------MagicString") != -1) {
            break;
        }

        // Write & Flush
        fout.write(data, 0, packet.getLength());
        fout.flush();

        }
      }

      // Close
      fout.close();

    }
    /* NOT REACHED */
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should really learn about UDP. Unlike TCP, UDP is unreliable and doesn't guarantee packets to be delivered to server from client or vice versa in sending order. Furthermore it won't take the same route always from client to server so there can be delays also.

Which means `--------MagicString` can come to the server before all the file packets received to the server. That means there is a chance that your file will be corrupted most of the time.

What you should do is implement an Application Level Protocol. For Example

```
FILENAME <File Name>
FILESIZE <File Size>
PACKET <Offset> <Length> <Packet>
FILEEND <File Name> // This will be the magic string
```

You should use above Application Level Protocol headers when sending data to Server and store those appropriately in variables.

```
ACKFILE <File Name>
ACKFSIZE <File Size>
ACKPACK <Offset>
ACKFILEEND <File Name>
```

For each packet the server should send an Acknowledgement packet like the above to let know the client that it received the packet. If an `ACK` packet didn't receive to the client that means the packet was lost so the client must resend it until the server receives it.

UDP is tricky and have a lot of Application Level coding involved.